# React Native camera on iOS is showing blank screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I am developing a React Native application for learning purposes. I am using this package, https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera. But when I open the camera page/ screen, it is just showing the blank screen with a spinner on top as below.

[image]

This is my code.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View
} from "react-native";
import { RNCamera } from "react-native-camera";

class EventDetails extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RNCamera
          ref={ref => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: "Permission to use camera",
            message: "We need your permission to use your camera",
            buttonPositive: "Ok",
            buttonNegative: "Cancel"
          }}
          androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
            title: "Permission to use audio recording",
            message: "We need your permission to use your audio",
            buttonPositive: "Ok",
            buttonNegative: "Cancel"
          }}
          onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
            console.log(barcodes);
          }}
        />
        <View
          style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center" }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}
            style={styles.capture}
          >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
      console.log(data.uri);
    }
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: "black"
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    alignSelf: "center",
    margin: 20
  }
});

export default EventDetails;
```

What is wrong with my code?

This is my iOS plist file for permissions.

[image]

Comment: Are you tested in real device ?

Answer (score 3):

You've done this correct, but you have to know the camera is not working on simulator but it will work correctly on external devices

Comment: I have the same code snippet it appears on my simulator with a blank screen, which is expected. However when i open it on an iPhone 8 it just crashes with no output.

Answer (score -1):

IMPORTANT:
In ios folder , execute the command "pod install" after linking manually the library. This solves my problem.